# Nedb Not working with javascript closure

Tags: javascript, nedb

I am using nedb, and to create new datastore I am using javascript closure. As I want my file path to be updated dynamically.
But after doing so, basic query is not working neither showing any error.

Please find below code,

```
var Datastore = require('nedb');
var path = require('path');
var config = require('../Config/config.js');
var db = {};

db.CLIoutput = (function(tempPath){
    return function(){ return tempPath ? new Datastore(path.join(tempPath,"CLIoutput.db")) : new Datastore(path.join(config.configuration.collection_path(), "CLIoutput.db"));}
})();

db.CLIoutput().loadDatabase();

db.CLIoutput().insert({"a":1}, function(err, res){
    console.log(res);
})

module.exports = db;
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The first call on CLIoutput will create the datastore, load it and forget it.

The second call will create the datastore, not load it, and queue up an insert for when it gets loaded.

Net result: nothing.